# Keeping track of background processes internally in cpp shell

Tags: c++

I'm writing a shell in cpp and I was hoping to get some advice. I have a command that will do an exec in the background, and I'm trying to keep track of which background processes are still running. I thought maybe I could keep track of the PID and do a string find on /proc/, but it seems to stay longer than it should. I'm testing it by using the sleep command, but it seems to always linger around wherever I look long after it should've finished. I'm probably just not doing the right thing to see if it is still running though.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are spawning off the child process via `fork()` or `forkpty()`, one reasonably good way to track the child process's condition is to have the parent process create a connected-socket-pair (e.g. via `socketpair()`) before forking, and have the child process call `dup2()` to make one end of that socket-pair its stdin/stdout/stderr file descriptor, e.g.:

```
// Note: error-checking has been removed for clarity
int temp[2];
(void) socketpair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, temp);

pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0)
{
   // We are the child process!
   (void) dup2(temp[1], STDIN_FILENO);
   (void) dup2(temp[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
   (void) dup2(temp[1], STDERR_FILENO);

   // call exec() here...
}
```

The benefit of this is that now the parent process has a file descriptor (`temp[0]`) that is connected to the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` of the child process, and the parent process can `select()` on that descriptor to find out whenever the child process has written text to its `stderr` or `stdout` streams, and can then `read()` on that file descriptor to find out what the child process wrote (useful if you want to then display that text to the user, or if not you can just throw the read text away), and most importantly, it will know when the child process has closed its `stderr` and `stdout` streams, because then the parent process's next call to `read()` on that file descriptor will indicate 0 aka EOF.

Since the OS will automatically close the child process's streams whenever it exits for any reason (including crashing), this is a pretty reliable way to get notified that the child process has gone away.

The only potential gotcha is that the child process could (for whatever reason) manually call `close(STDOUT_FILENO)` and `close(STDERR_FILENO)`, and yet still remain running; in that case the parent process would see the socket-pair connection closing as usual, and wrongly think the child process had gone away when in fact it hadn't.  Fortunately it's pretty rare for a program to do that, so unless you need to be super-robust you can probably ignore that corner case.

Comment: That's a really interesting way to do it that I never would've thought of. Plus, having the stdout and such is really useful. Thanks for a great answer.

Answer (score 0):

On a POSIX-like system, after you create any child processes using `fork`, you should clean up those child processes by calling [`wait` or `waitpid`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) from the parent process.  The name "wait" is used because the functions are most commonly used when the parent has nothing to do until a child exits or is killed, but `waitpid` can also be used (by passing `WNOHANG`) to check on whether a child process is finished without making the parent process wait.

Note that at least on Linux, when a child process has exited or been killed but the parent process has not "waited" for the child, the kernel keeps some information about the child process in memory, as a "zombie process".  This is done so that a later "wait" can correctly fetch the information about the child's exit code or fatal signal.  These zombie processes do have entries in `/proc`, which may be why you see a child "stay longer than it should", if that's how you were checking.

Comment: Thank you, that clears up my confusion about the remaining entries in /proc.